# Как это можно сверстать?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Саму линию получилось сверстать, а вот как написать в конце 80%, не знаю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используется position:absolute для текста. А вобще это ведь не статика и можно использовать progress bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.progress {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.progress__loading {
    background-color: #00cd6b;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress__loading" style="width: 80%">80% </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Alexandr Пожалуйста. Если ответ вам помог отметьте его решением.